# How can I set up multiple networks inside an Asus AIMesh network?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, vlan, asuswrt-merlin

I'm new to subnetting/VLANs and am looking to set up a second network inside my existing wifi mesh to isolate lees-then-secure devices like cheap Chinese IP cameras and a WiFi Instant Pot from my normal traffic (phones, PCs).

Can AI Mesh support this? If not, what is the typical home user solution for doing this? I currently have a Comcast gateway in bridge mode to feed WAN to my Asus mesh.

If I can't get a network within my mesh, how could I secure these devices so that if they were compromised, they wouldn't be exposed to devices with sensitive data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a business grade product from Cisco, Fortinet, Aruba or even Ubiquiti - AP Manager or Wifi Controller that supports vlans.

For example FortiWifi.

Comment: You're not targetting a "typical home user solution".

Answer (score 0):

Honestly just get a managed network switch/router (the ones used as a wifi-less vpn router). You can get a tplink one from Amazon for like 60 bucks [screenshot of device here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf0cx.jpg) You don't even need to set it up. Just plug it in and it will seperate the networks by default.